# Need some clarification with "blending" in direct3d 11

Tags: c++, direct3d, direct3d11

I have searched through google and found results that explain how blending works in direct3d 11. So I'm making this post just to validate on whether or not I completely understand these concepts.

For the most part, I somewhat understand the concept of blending. We blend colors by combining two colors and producing a final color. This is mostly done with two equations that direct3d has in the output merger stage.

`FinalColor = (Source Color * Source Blend Factor) + (Destination Color * Destination Blend Factor)`

and

`FinalAlpha = (Source Alpha * Source Alpha Blend Factor) + (Destination Alpha * Destination Alpha Blend Factor)`

The color sources `Source Color` and `Source Alpha` are defined by whatever the Pixel Shader outputs. And the destinations `Destination Color` and `Destination Alpha` are defined by whatever color is in the Render Target (backbuffer).

Now, i have a little bit of difficulty understanding the blend factors `Source Blend Factor`, `Destination Blend Factor`, `Source Alpha Blend Factor` and `Destination Alpha Blend factor`

Since I know that these blend factors are defined by `D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_BLEND_DESC`, i can use the member `SrcBlend` and assign it the flag `D3D11_BLEND_SRC_COLOR`... this would mean that the blend factor `Source Blend Factor` will have the color that the pixel shader outputs.

So do you think that i understand the concept of blending? or is there something that i am missing? (Feel free to correct me)

Answer (score 0):

The equations for blending are even more flexible than the ones you wrote above.  The generic blending equation is:

```
DestColor = Color1 <ColorOp> Color2
DestAlpha = Alpha1 <AlphaOp> Alpha2
```

While `Color1` is often the output from the pixel shader, it (along with `Color2`, `Alpha1`, and `Alpha2`) can be any of the values in the [`BLEND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476086(v=vs.85).aspx) enum.  Likewise, while the blend operator is usually `+`, it can actually be any of the values in the [`BLEND_OP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476088(v=vs.85).aspx) enum.  Together these provide the complete set of all possible normalized linear blending operations.  For an example of what values to use for "traditional alpha blending" see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929483/directx-render-to-texture-alpha-blending/27932112#27932112).

Comment: Thank you for your response and links. But i just have one more question (and this question might be silly, but i want to make sure i understand this), by filling out the structure `D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_BLEND_DESC`... am i just describing how the blending equation actually looks like right?

Comment: @Soon_to_be_code_master Correct - when you fill out the struct members, then use them (as a member of `D3D11_BLEND_DESC`) in a call to [`CreateBlendState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476500(v=vs.85).aspx), you'll end up with a blend state object that represents the equation you described based on the struct. When you apply this blend state using [`OMSetBlendState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476462(v=vs.85).aspx), the GPU will use the equation for blending in subsequent draw calls.